# Do all the points of inflection of curves $ k^2x^3 -kx^2 + x$ lie on one line?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There is a family of equations $ k^2x^3 -kx^2 + x$ where the points of inflection are given by $\dfrac {1}{3k}, \dfrac {7}{27k}$. It is stated that all the points of inflection lie on one line, which can be verified by factoring $\dfrac {7}{27k}$ into $\dfrac {7}{9} \times \dfrac {1}{3k}$. However I have some issue with this concept.

I believe that they would be in a straight line if the graph was not y against x, but rather $\dfrac {7}{27k}$ against $\dfrac {1}{3k}$ (somewhat like a parametric function). However checking gradients by calculation, we get $\dfrac {7}{9}$ every time. How is this possible? My intuition leads me to believe that the points of inflection would not be on a line, but rather on a curve. Please explain how the points lie on one line and if I have a misconception please point it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for a given k, the point of inflection is $\left(\frac{1}{3k}, \frac{7}{27k}\right)$.  That is, $x= \frac{1}{3k}$ and $y= \frac{7}{27k}$.  Because, as your quotation say, $\frac{7}{27k}= \frac{7}{9}\frac{1}{3k}$,  That says that $y= \frac{7}{9}x$, a straight line.  The inflection points, for different k, all lie on that line.

Comment: So you take them as x and y values that'll occur regardless? And the relationship between them is 7/9, ok got it. So then we can describe them as being a few of the points on the line but not all.